# Cannot pass custom result from resolver to Graphql

Tags: graphql, sequelize.js, apollo

I am trying to fetch data with sequelize with an attribute and pass it to graphql.
The result is fine in console but the graphql query is returning null for the attribute field.

my resolver

```
    getUnpayedLessons: async (_, args, { models }) => {
  const { Attendance, Student } = models;
  return await Attendance.findAll({
    include: {
      model: Student,
    },
    where: {
      fk_lessonsSerieId: { [Op.is]: null },
    },
    attributes: ["id", [sequelize.fn("count", sequelize.col("absenceFlag")), "unpayedLessons"]],
    group: ["student.id"],
  });
},
```

query

```
getUnpayedLessons {
  id
  unpayedLessons
  student {
    id
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
```

schema

```
type UnpayedLessons {
  id: Int
  unpayedLessons: Int
  student: Student
  }

extend type Query {
  getUnpayedLessons: [UnpayedLessons]
  }
```

and this is the console.log of the resolver when I run the query

```
    [
   attendance {
    dataValues: { id: 2, unpayedLessons: 8, student: [student] },
    _previousDataValues: { id: 2, unpayedLessons: 8, student: [student] },
    _changed: Set {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
     _schema: null,
     _schemaDelimiter: '',
      include: [Array],
      includeNames: [Array],
      includeMap: [Object],
      includeValidated: true,
      attributes: [Array],
      raw: true
     },
]
```

and from graphql

```
    {
  "data": {
    "getUnpayedLessons": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "unpayedLessons": null,
        "student": {
          "id": 2,
          "__typename": "Student"
        },
        "__typename": "UnpayedLessons"
      },
     ]
    }
   }
```

Any idea how I can have unpayedLessons passed to graphql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this you need to check what is returned from DB, the shape:

```
const values = await Attendance.findAll({...
console.log( values );
// adapt structure to match query requirements
// finally return
return values;
```

Comment: My bad, actually the result in the console ( [attendance { datavalues { ... ) is exactly that. I changed the resolver here for clarity but I have the console.log as you described in reality. DataValues seems to me in the same shape as my query. no?

Comment: `DataValues` is not a part of desired query result - array of type UnpayedLessons ... convert/adapt to required shape

Comment: Thank you, got it to work! But is not really clear why. Or better why wasn't working before. Is only the custom attribute that wasn't passed, and also is in the same shape when I don't put the custom attribute and never had any problems...

Comment: IDK ... hmm, squelize wasn't designed to satisfy apollo but probably apollo could be/was adapted to work with some **common**/possible data structures [returned from libs/DB/adapters] and is able to match them with required return types - not all use cases